# How to get usb to work on Virtual Box Kali Linux

Tags: usb, virtualbox, external-hard-drive, kali-linux

How to get usb to work on Virtual Box Kali Linux?

I have tried to install the extension pack and I still can't see the external drive on linux.

Comment: Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and then do yourself a favour and switch to some other distribution, e.g. a Debian based one. You'll be able to use all the tools Kali has, but all your "how do I get X to work" problems will magically disappear. Kali is meant to be put on an USB stick, and then you walk into some building with it and do penetration testing. It's not meant to run in a virtual environment, it's not meant for beginners, and even the experts don't use it for daily work.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on one I should try?

Comment: As I wrote: Any Debian-based one, because Kali is also Debian-based, so it'll be familiar. Ubuntu is popular with beginners. (I myself use Devuan). Wikipedia has [an overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Debian-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a answer to this question if I do I will post.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what you did, however this is simply the reason you're not pursuing your question any longer rather than a *solution* to your question.

Comment: Twisty Impersonator is right.  This isn't an answer and isn't the right way to handle this.  It's likely to attract downvotes as not an answer or be deleted.  If you no longer want to pursure the question, you can just delete it (but this must be deleted first since you can't delete a question with an accepted answer, even if it is your own.  If you delete too many of your own posts, it can trigger some automated limits on your account, so it would be worth identifying everything you want deleted and ask a moderator to do it for you.